# Deezer Native SDK: How to jump to track?

Tags: python, sdk, deezer

What is the correct way to jump to a specific track when playing an album with the [Deezer Native SDK](https://developers.deezer.com/sdk/native)? I have tried to extend the [Python example](https://github.com/deezer/native-sdk-samples/tree/master/PythonSample) with the following function:

```
    def playback_3(self):
        self.log("3 => {}".format(self.context.dz_content_url))
        self.player.play(command=PlayerCommand.JUMP_IN_TRACKLIST, index=3)
```

in `myDeezerApp.py`. This indeed does play track number 3 (the fourth from the album), but afterwards continues with the one after the one that was played before I jumped to 3.

E.g. I was playing track no 0, then I call `playback_3`, then track no 3 is playing. When it's over, the playback continues with track no 1. However, I would like it to continue with track no 4.

How do I achieve this? I also tried `START_TRACKLIST` instead of `JUMP_IN_TRACKLIST` but that shows the same behavior.

**In short**: What I am trying to achieve is to start the playback at a given track from some album and have the player consecutively play all following tracks (without calling `player.play` for each track).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good way is to store the current index in the track list in a variable `current_track_index`.

When you want to jump to the next 3rd track add 3 to the index

```
next_3rd_track_index = current_track_index + 3
```

and call `self.player.play` like this:

```
def playback_next_3rd_track(self):
    self.player.play(command=PlayerCommand.START_TRACKLIST, index=next_3rd_track_index)
```

The `JUMP_IN_TRACKLIST` is obsolete, confusing and should not be used anymore.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, but the 3 was just a hard-coded dummy example. And the problem is the same, regardless of whether I use `JUMP_IN_TRACKLIST` or `START_TRACKLIST`. (I've added a summary to the question to make clearer what I'm trying to do.)

Comment: Is there a method to update the *internal* track index of the player?

Comment: I am not sure it will answer to your question but there is currently a bug in the lib. When you force the specific index it will not be the index+1 track that will be played just after. I should be fixed in a next release.

Comment: it should be fine now with the 1.2.0